# Java in memory SQL Table like data structure

Tags: java, sql, data-structures

Several times I have wanted a data structure that is similar to a SQL Table
where you can select on various fields and multiple fields. Similar to an in memory SQL implementation except that I don't want to store that many objects in the data structure.

**I also require the object to be serializable through standard Java means.**

I have done this before with multiple hash tables or custom hash keys but it ended up being a lot of code and very specific the problem.

I have also used Groovy with its closure ability and gpath to help but I don't always have it available (different projects).

*EDIT: I think my problem is more of an object traversal/selection problem 
Here are some interesting projects:*

- http://josql.sourceforge.net/
- http://homepages.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/~djp/JQL/
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/03/java-object-querying-using-jxpath.html
- http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ (I used this in the past and it was.... slow...)
- http://jedi.codehaus.org/ Jedi

However the downside to most of these projects is that they are much slower than accessing the objects directly (non reflection getter/setter) and definitely slower than an index (hash).

Comment: Are you going to query some standalone snapshot of data? What about multithreading, locking, transactions, inserts/updates? If any of above possible - I'd 100% agree with @Alex.

Comment: @Osw No this purely for convenience. I don't need the ACID nature of RDBMS. I need the query ability.

Comment: think these links might be helpful: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html and http://almaer.com/blog/hibernate-3-testing-with-in-memory-pluggable-persistence

Answer (score 3):

[JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), among others, have fully in-memory databases.

Comment: The issue with those guys is that do not give me data structures that I can marshal/serialize. I'm looking for something I can XStream.

Comment: Although I suppose I could make some kind of generic data object to represent a table and on unmarshal gets loaded to an in-memory singleton rdbms but this has problems with thread safety if its not thread safe and lots of thread blocking if it is.

Comment: I doubt you'll find something that satisfies both requirements. My suggestion: use a serializable POJO to take a snapshot of the tables in the in-memory db, and then serialize that. Going the other way would be trivial as well, just unmarshall the XStream into a POJO and then load the data into the in-memory db.

Comment: Thinking along the same lines. :) There are probably several reasonable ways to handle the concurrence issues, depending on how available the in memory db has to be, and whether you need to make a hot copy, or can take the db offline to the affected threads.

Comment: I think most of my problems stem with Java's lack of builtin object graph traversal. C#'s LINQ and Groovy's GPath make traversing and objects based on different properties much easier than Java.

Answer (score 2):

What concerns you about using in-memory SQL storage for these purposes? You'd save a ton of development time; performance overhead is really insignificant. You risk much more by trying to implement this yourself.

Comment: It sounds like (to me anyway) he was looking for an alternative to building his own. Also, this isn't really an answer and might be better as a comment on the original question.

Comment: I don't want to build my own (hence the Q). I can't just use an in memory database the tables are not serializable data structures. In other words I can't send a whole db table over the wire through JAXB (enter your favorite serialization technology here) or save it to a file.